# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes'). I got this mistake, but I can't get through and solve the problem. Error shows  this line

```
     {addOption && addOption.length && (
                      <Select
                        onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
                        labelId="demo-customized-select-label"
                        id="demo-customized-select"
                        // value={addOption[i]}
                        value={addOption[i]}
                        multiple
                        onChange={(ev) => handleadd(ev, i)}
                        renderValue={() => {
                          return selectedOptionNames[i];
                        }}
                        input={<BootstrapInput />}
                      >
                        <MenuItem value={1} disabled>
                          FILE
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={2}>
                          <Checkbox checked={addOption[i].includes(2)} />
                          <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[1]}</ListItemText>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={3}>
                          <Checkbox checked={addOption[i].includes(3)} />
                          <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[2]}</ListItemText>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem value={4}>
                          <Checkbox checked={addOption[i].includes(4)} />
                          <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[3]}</ListItemText>
                        </MenuItem>
                      </Select>
```

Comment: the error sayed addOption[i] is undefined could you show us what contain the variable addOption ?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (props.activeTab === 1) {
      setLoading(true);
      Service.getService(searchText, userId).then((response) => {
        setLoading(false);
        setItem(response);
        setAddOptionNumbers(
          Array.from(Array(response.length).keys()).map((key) => {
            return "Add Option";
          })
        );
        setAddOption(
          Array.from(Array(response.length).keys()).map((key) => {
            return [1];
          })
        );
      });
    }
  }, [searchText, userId, props.activeTab]);

Comment: where `i` is coming from, its definitely going out of bound and thats why you are getting error. so update code snippet with `i` value source.

Answer (score 1):

you are getting this error because you are calling the method on a undefined index the array index you are calling it on is undefined you need to make sure to call the include method on a defined string or array as a whole not a index
Try calling the includes method on the array itself and not a index it should work

Answer (score 0):

As per your code snippet **addOption** is an array. So, you should have to perform the includes method on the array itself, not on a single array element. Check this out in your Menu Items :

```
<MenuItem value={X}>
   <Checkbox checked = { addOption.includes(X) } />
   <ListItemText> { addOptionNames[X-1] } </ListItemText>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: New err :     The `value` prop must be an array when using the `Select` component with `multiple`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@SamRaitan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19916003/samraitan) has rightly pointed out, you are trying to call the method on an undefined array index.

As a timely solution, you can use `conditional rendering`

```
<MenuItem value={2}>
  <Checkbox checked={addOption[i] && addOption[i].includes(2)} />
  <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[1]}</ListItemText>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Other possibilities would be,
* Value of ```i``` greater than / equal to array index,
* ```addOption``` not being properly defined, or it's state not being properly defined

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is related to the fact that `addOption[i]` is undefined at the point where you are trying to use the `includes` method. To avoid this error, you should ensure that `addOption[i]` is defined before calling `includes` on it.

You can modify the relevant part of your code like this:

```
<MenuItem value={2}>
  <Checkbox checked={addOption[i]?.includes(2)} />
  <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[1]}</ListItemText>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={3}>
  <Checkbox checked={addOption[i]?.includes(3)} />
  <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[2]}</ListItemText>
</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={4}>
  <Checkbox checked={addOption[i]?.includes(4)} />
  <ListItemText>{addOptionNames[3]}</ListItemText>
</MenuItem>
```

You can employ optional chaining to ensure that if `addOption[i]` exists, you can safely invoke the `includes` method on it. For further details on optional chaining, please consult this documentation: [Optional Chaining on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).